# yii2 DetailView time biger than 24hours

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Currently, I have this code in \kartik\detail\DetailView :

```
 [
    'attribute' => 'time',
    'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Time'),
    'format' => ['time', 'php:H:i:s'],
    'type' => \common\widgets\DetailView::INPUT_WIDGET, // setup custom widget
    'widgetOptions' => [
        'class' => \kartik\widgets\TimePicker::className(),
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showMeridian' => false
        ]
    ],
],
```

But this code supports only time to 24hours format. How would I change it to support 28 hours or 35 hours?

Thank you.

Comment: Are there other time formats than 12 and 24 at all?

Comment: No, I think there is only 12 and 24-hour format, but I'm wondering if there is a workaround for this problem, so I could enter more than 24 hours.

Comment: Could you please explain? I really can not wrap my head around it...